# Notify CDialog-Window when selecting another window

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc, onkillfocus

I got a dialog-based MFC-Tool that is supposed to show the title of a window of another application in a messagebox when i click on it.
My Problem is that the WM_KILLFOCUS doesn't work here. Maybe I'm doing it wrong.
I do the following:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyDlg, CDialog)
    ON_WM_KILLFOCUS()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

...
...

void CMyDlg::OnKillFocus( CWnd* pNewWnd )
{
    CDialog::OnKillFocus(pNewWnd);
    if(m_bSelectorModeActive)
    {
        HWND hwnd(GetForegroundWindow());
        TCHAR buf[512];
        ::GetWindowText(hwnd, buf, 512);
        MessageBox(buf);
    }
}
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is my guess

Replace HWND hwnd(GetForegroundWindow()); with GetActiveWindow(void) .

Answer (score 0):

The code you've shown shouldn't even compile. The `GetForegroundWindow` function provided by MFC doesn't return an `HWND`, so you can't initialize the `hwnd` variable using its return value.

If you want to get an `HWND`, you need to call `GetForegroundWindow` from the Windows API by escaping the call with `::`, just like you did for `GetWindowText`. So simply rewrite your code as follows:

```
void CMyDlg::OnKillFocus( CWnd* pNewWnd )
{
    CDialog::OnKillFocus(pNewWnd);
    if(m_bSelectorModeActive)
    {
        HWND hwnd(::GetForegroundWindow());
        TCHAR buf[512];
        ::GetWindowText(hwnd, buf, 512);
        MessageBox(buf);
    }
}
```

Beyond that, in looking at your code, one wonders that you seem to be ignoring the object-orientation MFC so humbly attempts to bring to the Windows API. You shouldn't need to work directly with window handles. And one could argue that the most compelling reason to use MFC is its `CString` class. There's no reason you should have to deal with an array of `TCHAR`s anymore. I might write this instead:

```
void CMyDlg::OnKillFocus( CWnd* pNewWnd )
{
    CDialog::OnKillFocus(pNewWnd);
    if(m_bSelectorModeActive)
    {
        CWnd* pForeWnd = GetForegroundWindow();
        CString windowText;
        pForeWnd->GetWindowText(windowText);
        MessageBox(windowText);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, thanks for your efforts.

Yes, i do use CStrings, this was just a little example of a bit more complex thing i do. My problem was not the function itself but the event WM_KILLFOCUS that didn't seem to work.
Maybe I was not clear enough here, sorry.

WM_ACTIVATE does what i need. It notifies my dialog when the focus is set and/or lost.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that my last answer was totally off-base. I tried to go just by looking at the documentation, and that's not always the smartest move. I actually tried it in a sample project, and I've updated my answer accordingly. The code that I've shown now works just fine. The only problem is that if you have any child controls on your dialog, you're going to get a lot of "false positive" `WM_KILLFOCUS` messages as the user switches between them.